# Can you explain the true identity of Murph's ghost?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In *Interstella*, when Murph was young she discovers something with gravity and calls it a ghost. But in the end of the movie she discovers it was Cooper. I still don't understand.

Comment: You might need to be a bit more specific with your question, though. You basically ask us to explain the entire timeline construction of the film to you. What specifically did you have difficulties to understand?

Answer (score -3):

Cooper travelled through dimensions, one of which was time.

That's about as simple as it gets.  The complexity lies around the whole "causal loop" thing that's so common in time travel stories.

The stories in the Back to the Future series are obvious (and simpler) examples.